# PHP - issue with trim()

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding, trim, spaces

### Context:

I'm saving a `.csv` file "*keys*" (the first line) into an `array $CSV` to get a multidimensionnal array of the file.
The keys containing multiple words keep their 1st and last spaces as 1st and last character. The file is encoded in `Windows-1252` which I convert to `UTF-8`.

### Process:

```
$keys = mb_convert_encoding($keys, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
$keys = trim(str_replace('"', ' ', $keys));
$keys = explode(';', $keys);
```

### Results:

> here are the firsts 2 keys, the 2nd one keeps its spaces.

**Initial process (key => value):**

```
[Commande] => C......
[ Date de création ] => 01/01/1970
```

**Using** `urlencode(substr($keys[$j], 0, 1))` **as value:**

```
[Commande] => C
[ Date de création ] => +
```

**Using** `rawurlencode(substr($keys[$j], 0, 1))` **as value:**

```
[Commande] => C
[ Date de création ] => %20
```

Using functions I found on other SO questions like `preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/', '', $keys)` always outputs `%20`.

I could skip this issue or work differently but I don't understand why can't I `trim()` these strings.

#### Full sample code:

```
$file = file(__DIR__ . '/path/to/' . $csv_file);
// Keys
$keys = mb_convert_encoding($file[0], 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
$keys = trim(str_replace('"', ' ', $keys));
$keys = explode(';', $keys);

$CSV = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < count($file); $i += 1) {
    $values = explode(';', $file[$i]);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($values); $j += 1) {
        $values[$j] = mb_convert_encoding($values[$j], 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
        $values[$j] = trim(str_replace('"', ' ', $values[$j]));
        $values = array_combine($keys, $values);
        $CSV[] = $values;
    }
}
die('<pre>' . print_r($CSV, true) . '</pre>');
```

Comment: I'm very unclear how these code snippets and that output are connected exactly. Can you produce a sample that is self-contained, which we can execute and clearly connect input to output?

Comment: Also, when inspecting what a string consists of, `bin2hex` is essential.

Comment: `trim()` will not remove spaces in between. Just do:-`$keys =str_replace('"', '', $keys);`

Comment: @deceze I did not know `bin2hex` could help me. I'm pasting the sample code.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I know that and I never mentionned I want to remove all the spaces, I want to do what trim() is made for.

Comment: ok got your point. do :-`$keys =str_replace(array('"',' '), ' ', $keys);` and check

Comment: The "full code" doesn't account for how `$keys` was created…!?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you have at some point a string `$keys` as `_item1_;_item2_;_item3_..` (underscore instead of space). if you trim that string, it will indeed only trim the first and last space, not the intermediate spaces

Comment: @AlivetoDie your code removed spaces but it also removed spaces in between.

Comment: @deceze sorry, little mistake while copying to my question. `$keys` is `$file[0]` converted to UTF8

Comment: So your question is why you get `[ Date de création ]`…?

Comment: @cypherabe sorry, context was unclear. It keeps spaces that should be removed by `trim()`

Comment: @deceze Yes, it should be `[Date de création]`. @AlivetoDie comment removed spaces but all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $keys = trim(str_replace('"', ' ', $keys));
> $keys = explode(';', $keys);
> ```

Presumably you're starting with this line:

```
Commande;"Date de création";"Something something"
```

You're then turning it into this line (you're *introducing* the spaces here):

```
Commande; Date de création ; Something something
```

Which you're then trimming (removing the spaces at the start and end of the line):

```
Commande; Date de création ; Something something
```

And *then* you're exploding the line:

```
array('Commande', ' Date de création ', ' Something something')
```

---

1. You need to `trim` each individual value *after* you have `explode`d the line, not before:

   ```
   $keys = array_map('trim', $keys);
   ```
2. You should use CSV-parsing functions to parse CSVs, not re-invent the wheel:

   ```
   $keys = str_getcsv($file[0], ';');
   ```
3. You should parse the entire CSV file using [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) for more efficiency:

   ```
   function read_and_convert_line($fh) {
       $values = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';');
       if (!$values) {
           return false;
       }

       return array_map(
           function ($value) { return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252'); }, 
           $values
       );
   }

   $fh = fopen(__DIR__ . '/path/to/' . $csv_file);
   $headers = read_and_convert_line($fh);
   $data = [];

   while ($row = read_and_convert_line($fh)) {
       $data[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
   }

   fclose($fh);
   print_r($data);
   ```

   This should eliminate the need for `trim` entirely.

Comment: ohh.. I could have avoided this error. Thanks for the advices too, I really appreciate.